# Is it possible to replicaset and shard a collection?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I've seen that for making a data distribution i can choose between ReplicaSet or Sharding.
Using a mongodb code with those parameters `--shardsvr --replSet`.

```
mongod --shardsvr --port 27021 --replSet rs1 --dbpath C:\data\data5 --bind_ip localhost
```

What i'm doing is making a shard server that is also a replicaSet or i'm just doing a shard?
And if i'm not doing both what should i write?

Edit

```
mongod --shardsvr --port 27020 --replSet rs1 --dbpath C:\data\data4 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --shardsvr --port 27021 --replSet rs1 --dbpath C:\data\data5 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --shardsvr --port 27022 --replSet rs1 --dbpath C:\data\data6 --bind_ip localhost
mongos --port 40000 --configdb rs0/localhost:27017
mongo --port 40000
rs.initiate( { _id : "rs1",  members: [   { _id: 0, host: "localhost:27020" },   { _id: 1, host: "localhost:27021" },   { _id: 2, host: "localhost:27022" }    ] })
sh.addShard( "rs1/localhost:27020,localhost:27021,localhost:27022")
sh.enableSharding("db")
sh.shardCollection("db.collection", { "_id" : 1 } )
```

When i do this kind of a code what i get is a collection sharded by 3 "servers" that are sharding and repliceSet aswell?
And with mongos on 40'000 port i can interface and make querys?

Comment: ok, thanks! i gonna edit my question with a better code so you might tell me if it's works? please

Comment: A shard is also a replica set.

Comment: A replica set and a sharded cluster have different purposes. Each shard in a sharded cluster needs to be a replicaset.  See [Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/sharding/index.html#sharded-cluster).

Comment: So what i'm doing here it's making 3 mongod shards that are ALSO replica set. am i right?
Your link i've read it several time but cant figuring out properly

Comment: @Minsky, of course you can deploy a single-member replica set. It is not the recommended design for production but in general it is working fine. The config server also must be a replica set, a stand alone it not possible. But nobody forces you to build a replica set with more two or more nodes.

Comment: @Minsky, are you sure about the stand alone config? [Release Note for MongoDB 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/#compat-remove-sccc) states: *To upgrade your sharded cluster to version 3.4, the config servers must be running as a replica set.*

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit great to know. I wasn't sure, but I believe I've built one for fun months ago, and it did work. To be honest, It doesnt make much sense to have replica sets and a stand alone config anyways!

Comment: @Minsky, I think the documentation is not 100% clear when it says "config servers for sharded clusters **can** be deployed as a replica set.", I just tested it. In deed, you can configure and start a stand alone config server - however you fail when you try to setup the mongos router with: `BadValue: configdb supports only replica set connection string` Of course - despite it is working - a single-member replica set does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replica sets and sharding serve different purposes:

- replica sets provide redundancy (if one node fails, data is also on other nodes)
- sharding provides scalability (if you have too much data for one server, you can spread it over multiple servers)

When you set up a sharded cluster, each shard can be (in theory) backed by a single node or a replica set. MongoDB currently requires that shards are backed by replica sets, in older versions single nodes were also permitted.

Therefore:

- Sharded cluster with single nodes = no redundancy. Each document is stored once, if any single node fails you lose data. But you can get scalability based on number of shards you deploy.
- Sharded cluster with backing replica sets = both scalability and redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

You created one shard which is a three-member replica set and one config server as a single-member replica sets. Every shard and every config server must be a replica set.

If you like to get several shards then you must use a different name for `--replSet`, e.g. rs1, rs2, rs3.

In production you should not create single-member replica sets unless you don't care about availability. Typically you would create another 3 shard nodes, then each shard is also replicated.

Maybe follow this tutorial [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)

Comment: What would be the use of a shard in a 1-repl set configuration? There so sharding possible there. You need at least one node out of the replica set. That was my point...